# Do Awakaned Mind and other pact spells of warlock outside the expanded list need to be learned?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, warlock

Sorry for the this newbie question, but I want to build a warlock (Great Old One patron) in D&D 5e, and I and the GM are new to the game.

For my understanding, once I have the requirements I should be able to use, at least the spells that are not on the ''expanded spells'' graphic, without needing to learn it.

The GM says that these spells are also in the list but the company didn't put them in this list.

Am I able to use Awakened Mind and Entropic Ward when I have the requirements but don't need to have learned them when I leveled up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are talking about two different things here...

The Expanded Spell List and your Patron Features are two distinct things.

Your Expanded Spell list is one of the five Class Features you get from your Patron. It is a collection of extra spells that Warlocks of a different Patron cannot learn, but *you can.* These have to be learned just like every other spell you learn.

So, the little graphic you were talking about (on page 110) is the list of those spells.

The other things you mentioned are your other four Patron Features, **not spells.**

Awakened Mind and Entropic Ward are class features that don't use spell slots and don't have to be 'learned' the same way a spell does. That's just a new thing you can do as you level up as a Warlock.

So yes....because your Patron is the Great Old One, you *automatically* gain use of those features once you reach the appropriate level in your class.

It's the same way that a Champion Fighter automatically learns 'Improved Critical' or 'Remarkable Athlete' without having to "pick them" as if they were spells.